# How to transfer PlayOnLinux and all it's files into my secondary hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, games, steam, playonlinux

So here is my problem, i have downloaded PlayOnLinux (Wine too) and i have installed in PlayOnLinux the steam platform.
From there (steam) i have downloaded some of my games but it takes too much space in my SSD (os) drive. I tried moving PlayOnLinux inside my secondary hard drive with all it's files but 1) could not change the path to access steam and 2) there were no applications when i opened PlayOnLinux.
To sum up i need help moving PlayOnLinux to my secondary hard drive with all the files and games so it does not "eat" space from my SSD.
Thank you for taking the time to read my post hope you help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I modified a post which I created in another thread and assume your SSD (or second hard drive in general) is already accessible, if I am wrong read the upper part of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/678294/448613).

### Moving Programs

- An easy way to move programs onto the second hard disc is creating [symlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link):

> With a symlink you move the actual file to another place and you on the former place create a symlink which directs to the new place - explained in easy words. I recommend, that **before you move files** you make a copy of them with an alternative name and delete them first, when everything is working.

- Now search for the programs/files you want to have on your second disc, it's likely that they are stored under  `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin` or `/bin`ⁱ. For steam's directory look [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227502/where-are-steam-games-installed).
- Make a backup of them in the same directory

  ```
   sudo cp <PATHtoFILE>/<filename> <PATHtoFILE>/<filename>_backup #it doesnt matter how you name your copy.
  ```
- Then copy your file on the second hard disc:

  ```
   sudo cp <PATHtoFILE>/<filename> /media/<user>/<nameOfyourDrive>/<filename> # the mountpoint you created earlier, your second hard disc
  ```
- And now you are able to create a symlink to its former place:

  ```
   sudo ln -s /media/<user>/<nameOfyourDrive>/<filename> <oldPath>/<filename> #creates a symbolic link from the old path to the second hard drive
  ```

> Test the programs or files, which you intend to move: If you recognize, that everything is working nicely, you can delete the backup, which you hopefully created earlier:

```
 sudo rm [-r] <PATHtoFILE>/<filename>_backup # removes backup-file or directory: '-r' only, when it's a directory
```

---

ⁱ Matter, that it's not sure that all parts of the programs are here. It may be possible, that they are in different directories or separated into more than only one. Furthermore it's likely that they access libraries from `/usr/lib/`or from elsewhere in the filesystem.