# How to install Ubuntu system on SSD and storage media on HDD?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I just installed a 240GB SSD on my laptop. So I have two drives, the SSD and a HDD. So, I have installed Windows on my SSD with 170GB memory. And I want to install Ubuntu on my SSD, too, with 30GB memory. But I want only the Ubuntu system that was installed on the SSD.

If I save any file like a document, photo, video, etc, I want to save it to my HDD. So the SSD should just be for the Ubuntu system and not for saving files.

How can I do that?
Please suggest a solution!

Comment: This thread does not have an accepted answer but you might find the information useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/678271/how-can-i-install-things-in-my-second-hard-drive

Comment: Are you trying to keep windows so you can dual boot?

Comment: Simple solution is to have separate /home on HDD, but better to keep /home inside / (root) and have all data on HDD in NTFS or ext4 formatted partition(s). http://askubuntu.com/questions/524943/dual-boot-with-ssd-and-hdd-storage & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/921778/windows-10-dual-boot-ubuntu-on-ssd-and-data-on-hdd & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670 & http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811198

Answer (score 1):

On installation make sure that you put the `/home` directory on the HDD. You can map your whole HDD (or only a partition) to the mount-point `/home`. This way everything you save in your `/home` directory would be saved on the HDD.

On the other hand you could create a completely new, separate, directory like `/data` that is a mount-point of your HDD(like `/dev/sdb1` or so) and contains all of your data. But this way you'll have to adjust all the relevant soft-links and hard-links to the new location.

Both options are viable.